# How to fix sending jsp page with a ajax call in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to make an ajax request that sends a value to my spring boot. However, once I incorporate the ajax call and it successfully passes the value to java it does not view the `jsp` page. Again I have the values being passed, but whenever I use `ModelAndView` or `Model` it seems to not change the page accordingly. We have tried changing around the format of the ajax call and it still does not work.

**JSP Code:**

```
 <script>
        var chaptersTest = ${ chapters };
        var totalChapters = chaptersTest.length;
        var codeBlock;

        for (var i = 0; i < totalChapters; i++) {

            codeBlock =


                '<div class="col-md-4">' +

                ' <a class="chapter_link" data-link="' + chaptersTest[i] + '" style="text-decoration: none; color: white"><div class="box warning">' +

                '  <h3>' + chaptersTest[i] + '</h3>' +

                '  </div></a></div>';

            $("#chapterArea").append(codeBlock);
        }


        //clicked links

        $('.chapter_link').click(function () {
            console.log("YoUR fUNCtION IS cLICKED");
            doSomething();
        });



        function doSomething() {
            var search2 = {
                "chapter": "riley"
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/ajax",
                data: JSON.stringify(search2),
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("It somewhat worked");
                }

            });

        }



    </script>
```

**Java Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView sectionView(@RequestBody BEntity benny, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String temp = benny.getChapter();
        ModelAndView secView = new ModelAndView();

        try {
            secView.setViewName("viewsections");
            //It is not sending the jsp to change the page

        } catch (Exception e) {
            secView.setViewName("error");

        }


        System.out.println("Test 2");
        return secView;
    }
```

**Application Properties:**

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**Object:**

```
public class BEntity {

    private String search; 
    private String chapter;
    private String section; 

    public String getSection() {
        return section; 
    }


    public String getChapter() {
        return chapter; 
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This was searched: " + search;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this.. I tried in the past https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ajax-example/

Comment: @RamPrakash So I looked at the code but it doesn't work

Comment: @RamPrakash The main problem I have is that I can't get any values or notification in the success field of the ajax call.